# Does Resurrection Remix exist for Asus_Z00E_2?

Tags: custom-roms, asus-zenfone-2, resurrection-remix-os

It is not on their website, but I can't believe they have skipped making a ROM for this device.

It looks like none of the official releases support this device. I really don't know why though.

Comment: Well there are a lot of ROMs for the Zenfone2 (https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone2) but many, if not all of them, are for the Z00A/Z008 variant. I don't know much about the Zenfone2, so I'm sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is just horrible that I am stuck with the default ROM. It is a nightmare. :) I was hoping to try Resurrection Remix, but until I started the installation I didnt realize it was not available for my phone. Cheers anyways.